# hibernate correct way to set default value on database side

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate, and I'm looking for the correct approach to set a default value on database side.

I hope the DDL generated by hibernate is equivalent to this:

```
create table SpaceGroup (
        name varchar(255) not null, 
        isProtected boolean default FALSE not null, 
        primary key (name)
)
```

Here is my entity declaration:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class SpaceGroup {
    @Id
    private String name;
    @ColumnDefault("FALSE")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean isProtected;
}
```

the problem with this approach is that hibernate didn't realize there is a db default value, so when I insert object it complains I do not give a value for a `not null` field:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.ziqi.models.SpaceGroup.isProtected
```

even adding a `@DynamicInsert` can not solve this issue

why hibernate not able to infer this field will be given a default value on **database side**? I believe `@DynamicInsert` is not even need if I understand it correctly.

Comment: To create a default value directly in the SQL table definition we can use the @Column annotation and set its columnDefinition parameter:

@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
private Boolean locked;

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize the variable and it sets that value as the default.
@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean isProtected = false;

Else, you can use columnDefinition property of the @Column annotation, for example:

@Column(columnDefinition=“boolean default false")
private Boolean isProtected;